# Convert str to float explicitly in Python 3

Tags: python, casting, typeerror

I am gettting a "TypeError: Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly" error because I am trying to divide a float by a string.

I am trying to cast the string to a float, but am still getting an error.

The string 'empNumber', is all digits but has a comma (ex: 112,000) - hence the "replace" function to strip the comma. I am drawing an error when I try to divide "final/decimal". How can I fix this type error?

```
def revPerEmployee():
    for ticker in sp500short:
        searchurl = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s="+ticker
        f = urlopen(searchurl)
        html = f.read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

        searchurlemp = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q/pr?s="+ticker+"+Profile"
        femp = urlopen(searchurlemp)
        htmlemp = femp.read()
        soupemp = BeautifulSoup(htmlemp, "html.parser")

        try:
            revenue2 = soup.find("td", text="Revenue (ttm):").find_next_sibling("td").text
            empCount2 = soupemp.find("td", text="Full Time Employees:").find_next_sibling("td").text 

        except:
            revenue2 = "There is no data for this company"
            empCount2 = "There is no data for this company"         

        if revenue2 == "There is no data for this company" or empCount2 == "There is no data for this company":
            lastLetter = ticker+": There is no data for this company"
        else:
            lastLetter = revenue2[len(revenue2)-1:len(revenue2)]
            empNumber = empCount2.replace(",", "")
            decimal = float(empNumber)

        if lastLetter == "B":
            result = revenue2[:-1]
            revNum = float(result)
            final = revNum * 1000000000.0
            revPerEmp = final/decimal
            print(ticker+": "+revPerEmp)

        elif lastLetter == "M":
            result = revenue2[:-1]
            revNum = float(result)
            final = revNum * 1000000.0
            #newnum = "{:0,.2f}".format(final)
            revPerEmp = final/decimal
            print(ticker+": "+revPerEmp)

        elif lastLetter == "K":
            result = revenue2[:-1]
            revNum = float(result)
            final = revNum * 1000.0
            #newnum = "{:0,.2f}".format(final)
            revPerEmp = final/decimal
            print(ticker+": "+revPerEmp)

        else:
            print(lastLetter)
```

Comment: There is a lot of irrelevant code here; you should strip your example to the relevant bit, and make sure it is correct. There is no variable `empNumber2` in your example. There is no indication where the error is. When you cast the string to a float, you don't even mention which error you're getting now. Read more about [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: I did say where I am drawing an error. The error occurs at the first occurance of "revPerEmp = final/decimal". The error says, "TypeError: Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly"

Comment: Or is it the line after? `print(ticker+": "+revPerEmp)`

Comment: As Octavian says, there is zero chance that you are getting the error you say you're getting on the line you say you're getting it.

Comment: @Obsidian yes my IDE is saying on line where print(ticker+": "+revPerEmp). What problem are you noticing?

Comment: You should do an `str(floatVariable)` while concatenating with a string. Or better use `print("{}:{}".format(ticker, revPerEmp))`

Comment: BTW, you can convert a string containing thousands separators to a float using `locale.atof`, and that will use the locale's separator and decimal point, so it can even handle strings like `'1.234.567,897'`, if the current locale uses that convention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`17 + "orange"` is nonsense, you can't add numbers and strings. You want

```
print("%s: %s" % (ticker, revPerEmp))
```

(you can switch `%s` for other formats, like `%.2f`), or

```
print(str(ticker) + ": " + str(revPerEmp))
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Sorry for my ignorance

Comment: No problem with ignorance, that's what the site is for. Just wanted you to realise the fact that the better your question writeup is, your chances of getting an answer rise. Ask the right question the right way, and a quick answer is much more likely. You might also want to peruse the Stack Overflow [help on asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your program assumes that what is obtained from the URL request is a number in the form of digits followed by a suffix (K, M or B).  This is not tested for.

There are also two suggestions to improve your code.  First, you do use a try ... except clause to check when data cannot be obtained.  You can also use it if conversion fails.  The message "There is no data for this company" could be printed in the except clause.

Second, you have three if clauses very much alike, suggesting they can be condensed.  A python dictionary can be used for the suffix values.

```
SUFFIX_VALUES = { 'K': 1000.0, 'M': 1000000.0, 'B': 1000000000.0 }
try:
  # taken from your code
  revenue2 = soup.find("td", text="Revenue(ttm):").find_next_sibling("td").text
  empCount2 = soupemp.find("td", text="Full Time Employees:").find_next_sibling("td").text 
  revNum = float(revenue2[:-1])
  empNumber = empCount2.replace(",", "")
  decimal = float(empNumber)
  lastLetter = revenue2[-1]
  final = revNum * SUFFIX_VALUES[lastLetter]
  revPerEmp = final/decimal
  print("%s: %d" % (ticker, revPerEmp))
except:
  print(ticker + ": There is no data for this company")
```

Now, if data is missing from the URL request, if conversion fails, or if the suffix is wrong, the program will execute the except clause.

Comment: I really appreciate this